# What if features are partially dependent ? (don't know a better way to describe it)

Tags: feature-selection

I am working on data of a telecommunication company customers. One of the features indicates the type of internet connection a customer has and 3 other categorical features(OnlineSecurity, OnlineBackup, DeviceProtection). When customers don't have internet service these features take a value of zero, otherwise they can be Zero or One.

Is there a better way to treat t these features rather than leaving them as they are (one-hot-encoded categorical features)?

Comment: can you explain more? maybe give an example or post some code?

Comment: May check the question again, I made some editing

Comment: I am not sure I can answer that. i will share the link with some seniors I know